# How the step down mini transformers operate in too small current in the primary

Tags: transformer

For electronic circuits I use step down mini transformers. That can transform the residential 230V AC voltage nearly 14V. 
I know that (IV)primary = (IV)secondary. That means the secondary current should much higher than the primary current. I measured the currents in my electronic circuits are in mili range. That means the current in the primary must be in mili range and lower than the secondary current.

if Vprimary = 230V, Vsecondary = 14V then K = 14/230 = 0.061
Now, if I assume that Isecondary = 1Amp then the Iprimary = 1*0.061 = 61mA

That is too small. Moreover, the secondary currents are usually less than 1Amp. In this case the current in the primary should smaller.

It seems somewhat awkward to me that our residential main can supply too tinny current??

Comment: Why do you think that is too small?  Current is drawn by a circuit (it takes only what it needs), not imposed upon it by the power source.

Comment: Yeah, 61mA from 230V is still 14 Watts, that's actually a huge amount of power. That's enough energy to charge almost 3 mobile phones at 1A 5V each, or run 6 Raspberry Pis at the same time.

Comment: Totally agree with Majenko. There is no minimum current from a supply - **only a maximum current**. The amount of current taken is determined by the load, not by the supply.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer moves **power** from one location to another, so if you have a transformer supplying, say, 1000 watts to a load from its secondary, then its primary must capture that 1000 watts from the mains and transfer it to the load through the secondary.

Assuming that the 1000 watt load draws 10 amperes from a 100 volt secondary means that with 240 volt mains supplying the primary, the mains current into the primary must be:

$$I=\frac PE = \frac{1000\text{ watts}}{240\text{ volts}} = 4.17\text{ amperes}$$

Interestingly, if the load draws 50 amperes out of a 20 volt secondary, that's still 1000 watts and the primary must still draw 4.17 amperes from the mains, as earlier.

In your case, with a 14 watt load drawing 1 ampere from a 14 volt secondary, the current required into the primary, from the mains, will be:

$$I=\frac PE = \frac{14\text{ watts}}{240\text{ volts}} = 58\text{ milliamperes}$$

so you can see that rather than just being able to to supply a tiny current, the mains will supply whatever current the load requires, up to the mains' limit.

Comment: In transmission line we step up the voltages so that the current will reduce.. Suppose a transmission line supplies 32KV. Then how much current would flow through the line?? Though it depends on load but I want to know the amount of current that flows through our transmission lines in this case.

Comment: @EMFields: You have some shifty decimal points in your answer.  Second line should be "capture that 1000 watts", and third paragraph should say "must draw 4.17 amperes"

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I changed from 100 watts to 1000 watts for a more dramatic example but didn't follow through by changing all the units like I should have.

Comment: @Raihan: If the load dissipates 1000 watts and that 1000 watts  originates from a 32kV source, then, neglecting losses, the 32kV source must be able to supply I = 1000 watts/32000 volts = 0.03125 amperes.